# Read html tags in Freemarker inside Word (docx) template, received from Java

Tags: java, html, freemarker, docx

I have a problem with docx template not recognizing html tags like < b>< /b>. I can read simple parameters, object parameters and iterate over them, but I have problem with parsing these damn tags...

**Problem**:
I have a String in Java App, for example: "This is < b>example< /b> of string". I am sending this String to Freemarker template in Word (docx). Now I except, that when I will genrate raport using this templete, I will receive:

This is **example** of string

Instead I am receiving:

```
This is <b>example</b> of string
```

I did some research and it looks like Word doesn't supply html tagging, nor other tagging. What I already tried was for example wrapping into **[#escape x as x?html][/#escape]** or using different tags like **< strong>, < bold>** and so on. I was looking also inside a docx structure, where I found that there are tags like **<w:t>,<w:r>** and tried to wrap those inside Java String, but result was the same. Partially workaround was using **key:value LinkedHashMap** where i printed key as a normal font, and value was bolded inside Word. It was ok until I came across double for loop (key is also esencial to print out in raport, so I can't artificially create random key). I would be very grateful for any tips how to achieve my goal because I'm out of ideas;)

PS: I tried also write some kind of instruction in JavaScript inside docx template, but it never worked out, perhaps it is becasuse I am not used to js;x

Comment: Did you look at the generated XML directly (if you extract the docx as zip, there are XML files inside)? I suspect you don't really understand what's going on on that level. You have to replace the HTML tags with WordML tags, but you have to *avoid* XML escaping, or else the tags are just shown as text for the user.

Comment: Agree that I might not understand that level, but i did some research and there was nothing which would actually work with WordML tags. Do you have in mind some specific tags which works inside .docx as bold? x|

Comment: To be clear, I have no expertise with WordML. But in what way it did not work? If you just see the tags appearing as plain text when you open the generated docx in World, then you have an escaping issue there.